What happens when abortTransation() or endSession() fails using mongoose?
I have a typical transaction operation using mongoose in my nodeJS/Express application:
let session = null;
try {
  session = await mongoose.startSession();
  await User.create({ ... });
  await Otp.create({ ... });
  await session.commitTransaction();
}
catch (error) {
  await session.abortTransaction();
}
finally {
  session.endSession();
}

However, I have learned that both abortTransaction() and endSession() can throw errors, which is why I wonder what happens when these operations fail? Will mongoose clean up the mess by itself? Or do I need to periodically re-attempt to abort the transaction/end the session until it works or some other weird stuff like that? Can't seem to find any information about how to handle this as every tutorial I see just leave the code the way I wrote it in the code block above without even wrapping the abort or end calls in their own try catches.

It throws an error because you forgot to start the transaction session.startTransaction(),   session.withTransaction(), db.transaction() etc. Regarding the mess - mongo rolls back the transaction unless you successfully committed it. Mongoose (the models) is a different story. Model.create is relatively safe - you just don't use the objects created within the transaction. Other operations might keep the changes in the objects, even if the model.save was rolled back. I'd suggest to wrap it with tests to ensure it does what you intend it to do in various scenarios.


I have learned that both abortTransaction() and endSession() can throw errors, which is why I wonder what happens when these operations fail?

abortTransaction() will throw an error only when you attempt to abort a transaction that has been commited already or when no transaction is alive.
Refer
endSession() won't throw any error. Refer
The abortTransaction() will only throw an error, when your code be like this.
try {
  session = await mongoose.startSession();
  //...
  await session.commitTransaction();
  await session.abortTransaction();
}
catch (error) {
  await session.abortTransaction();
}

Or:
try {
  session = await mongoose.startSession();
  //...
  await session.abortTransaction();
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}

Proper usage is the key here.

could it not throw network errors though?

@OscarR - It will but it's not related to transaction. It should be handled by the error handling middleware. Network error is related to MongoDB not specifically to the transaction. Network error will occur at any kind of db operation. And any error if happened, the finally block will get executed and the session will be ended so the transaction will get aborted.

ok thank you for your help!
